# NIM - Installing client with custom bosinst

Tags: aix

I'm trying to install a client with `lpp_source_AIX7200-02`, `spot_AIX7200-02`, and a custom `bosinst.data`.

My goal is to install the OS with ssh and CDE desktop. By the way, when I complete the installation process I'm unable to find the CDE, yet there are no errors during the installation. I've no problems about ssh if I use a NIM 7.2 with lpp_source_AIX7200-02, spot_AIX7200-02.

Using a NIM master 7.1, (with spot and lpp 7.1) I can't find both (ssh and CDE) after the installation is succeeded.

This is my `bosinstdata` template.

```
CONSOLE = Default
INSTALL_METHOD = overwrite
INSTALL_EDITION = enterprise
PROMPT = no
EXISTING_SYSTEM_OVERWRITE = yes
INSTALL_X_IF_ADAPTER = yes
RUN_STARTUP = no
RM_INST_ROOTS = no
ERROR_EXIT =
CUSTOMIZATION_FILE =
INSTALL_TYPE =
BUNDLES =
RECOVER_DEVICES = Default
BOSINST_DEBUG = yes
ACCEPT_LICENSES = yes
ACCEPT_SWMA =
DESKTOP = CDE
INSTALL_DEVICES_AND_UPDATES = yes
IMPORT_USER_VGS =
ALL_DEVICES_KERNELS = yes
GRAPHICS_BUNDLE = yes
SYSTEM_MGMT_CLIENT_BUNDLE = yes
OPENSSH_CLIENT_BUNDLE = yes
OPENSSH_SERVER_BUNDLE = yes
FIREFOX_BUNDLE = no
KERBEROS_5_BUNDLE = no
SERVER_BUNDLE = no
REMOVE_JAVA_5 = yes
HARDWARE_DUMP = yes
ADD_CDE = no
ADD_GNOME = no
ADD_KDE = no
ERASE_ITERATIONS = 0
ERASE_PATTERNS =
MKSYSB_MIGRATION_DEVICE =
TRUSTED_AIX = no
TRUSTED_AIX_LSPP = no
TRUSTED_AIX_SYSMGT = yes
SECURE_BY_DEFAULT = no
ADAPTER_SEARCH_LIST =
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: See also: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.install/nim_op_showlog.htm

Answer (score 0):

The NIM server must be at the same or higher AIX level as the client you are installing.